# I used [scrollView addSubView:imageView] but imageView doesn't appear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'm developing iPad app using SplitView.
And I put UIScrollView in DetailView by using Interface Builder.
Then I add `IBOutlet UIScrollView scrollView;` in detailViewController.h that was automatically created by Xcode.
And connected this scrollView to UIScrollView in DetailView.xib .

And I added below code to DetailViewController.m .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    UIImageView *tempView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.jpg"]];  
    self.imageView = tempView;  
    [tempView release];  
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);  
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;  
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;  
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;  
    scrollView.delegate = self;  
    [scrollView addSubView:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

I think by add this code, scrollable image is shown in detailView. But nothings appear.

Please teach me how to display UIScrollView in detailView.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `frame` property, like this:

```
tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100); //x, y, width, height
```

Also, why are you first creating a tempView, then point `self.imageView` to it, and then release them both in the end? Wouldn't it be more readable and maintainable to just skip the `self.imageView` and just use `tempView`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the UIScrollView delegate and return the imageView. This will help in handling the resizing the image

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imgView;
}
```